# I'm facing problem when i trying to set and get session by using Asp.Net Core Rest API 6.0 and Angular v.14

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm posting user related data from angular to asp.net core rest api 6.0,when i post data from angular to rest api controller from there by using UserSignUp() method i'm setting session and in angular side after setting session i'm trying to get session data by using this method of controller class GetSessionData() but its showing null data for all those properties which i set in UserSignUp() method,below is my code

**Controller class code**

```
[HttpGet("GetSessionData")]
        public IActionResult GetSessionData() 
        {
            var sessionData = new
            {
                Id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Id"),
                UserName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userName"),
                Role = HttpContext.Session.GetString("role")
            };
            return Ok(sessionData);
        }
```

**Post Method**

```
[HttpPost("UserSignUp")]
        public IActionResult UserSignUp(UserSignUpModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Id", model.Id);
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("userName", model.UserName);
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("role", model.Role);
                    new UsersHandler().PostUserSignUp(model.ToEntity());
                }
                return Created(Request.Path, model);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex);
            }       
        }
```

**Angular side component class code**

```
signUpData() {
    this.authService.PostUserSignUp(this.signUp).subscribe((response) => {
      // Call the GetSessionData method to retrieve session data
      this.authService.GetSessionData().subscribe(
        (sessionDataResponse) => {
          console.log(sessionDataResponse);
          if (sessionDataResponse && sessionDataResponse.id && sessionDataResponse.userName && sessionDataResponse.role) {
            this.authService.setSessionCookies(sessionDataResponse);
          }
        });
    });
    this.SignUpForm.reset();
  }
```

**Angular Service Methods**

```
GetSessionData(): Observable<Login>{
    return this.http.get<Login>(this.usersBaseApiUrl + '/GetUserLogin',{ withCredentials : true});
  }

  setSessionCookies(data:Login) {
    this.cookieService.set('id', data.id.toString());
    this.cookieService.set('userName', data.userName);
    this.cookieService.set('role', data.role);
  }
```

**Program.cs file code**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddCors(a =>
{
    a.AddDefaultPolicy(
        opt =>
        {
            opt.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying `sessionDataResponse` is null, right?

Comment: Can you send the code for your angular service?

Comment: In this method GetSessionData() of controller class i don't have data in Id,userName and role,these all properties showing null

Comment: Above now i include angular service methods

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible causes based on what you gave us here.

First thing to do is put UseSession(); above UseRouting(); in your middleware.

Second thing I would try is to use `HttpContext.Session` in your API methods before you are trying to get or set values. This will ensure the Session is started.

Third thing to do is to triple check your CORS is configured properly. Although if you have other Angular methods working with your API already this probably isn't the issue.

Here is an example:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("http://your-angular-domain.com")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());  // This one is important for sessions
```

Next thing I would check is my Angular service to make sure that I am asking for what I need correctly. Something like:

`this.http.get('https://your-api-domain.com/endpoint', { withCredentials: true })`

There are a few other things to check, but without more of your code, I can't give you accurate information.

Comment: 1- For middleware i am following that order which is provided by microsoft "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order " but i follow what you said about changing order of UseSession() & its still null in all properties. 2- I don't what you are saying that "use HttpContext.Session in your API methods before you are trying to get or set values" while i'm already using it before set and get session. 3- I add it in code now. 4- I also add it in my angular service. I follow all the steps but its still null in the properties.

Comment: I solved my problem by that way in this action method UserSignUp() where i am setting session data below after that in that same method i get session data into required variables and by Ok(response) and i get it into angular side.In my above code when i get session data into separate action method GetSessionData() during that i lost my session data that's why i don't get any data at that time and getting null.

Comment: I am glad you were able to figure it out! Nice work!

Comment: Corey its your thanks that you help me in that problem

Comment: I might be able to help but you're the one who made the change and got it working. Credit is all yours! Keep coding, you're doing great.